# Possible lossy conversion from int to byte error in byte methods

Tags: java, byte, type-conversion

I have a byte variable

```
byte A;
```

and the setters-getters methods

```
    public void setA(byte A) throws NumberBelowEqualZeroException{
        if(A > 0)
            this.hoursPerWeek = hoursPerWeek;
        throw new NumberBelowEqualZeroException();
    }

    public byte getWorkingHoursPerWeek(){
        return hoursPerWeek;
    }
```

when I try to set the variable in main

```
AClass.setA(0);
```

NetBeans complains with the message *incompatible types. Possibly lossy conversion from int to byte*. None of the above are int. I cannot understand what is going on. Should I convert byte type like `byte A = new Byte(A)`? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now try

```
AClass.setA((byte)0)
```

It complains because constant 0 is an int